# Ignore empty "$_POST" values in MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have three select box menus:

```html
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" size="5">
  <option value="">Delete</option>
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>

<select name="category2" id="category2" class="form-control" size="5">
  <option value="">Delete</option>
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>

<select name="category3" id="category3" class="form-control" size="5">
  <option value="">Delete</option>
  <option value="0">Option 0</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

The selected options are sent with ajax to a server sided script. Here I catch the selected options and use them in MySQL queries:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM itemSparse 
INNER JOIN item
ON item.id = itemSparse.id
LEFT JOIN itemsubtest
ON itemsubtest.subclass = item.Material
INNER JOIN itemModifiedAppearance
ON itemModifiedAppearance.ItemID = itemSparse.id
INNER JOIN ItemAppearance
ON ItemAppearance.identifier = itemModifiedAppearance.ItemAppearanceID
INNER JOIN manifestInterfaceData
ON manifestInterfaceData.ID = ItemAppearance.DefaultIconFileDataID
WHERE 1=1
";

$query.= " WHERE item.ClassID = 4 ";

if(isset($_POST["is_category"]))
{
     $query .= " AND item.Material = '".$_POST["is_category"]."'";
}

if(isset($_POST["is_category2"]))
{
    $query .= " AND itemSparse.OverallQualityID = '".$_POST["is_category2"]."'";
}

if(isset($_POST["is_category3"]))
{
     $query .= " AND itemSparse.StatModifier_bonusStat1 = '".$_POST["is_category3"]."'";
 }
```

**The problem:**

The queries are only working when all three select menus have a selected value. If not all three menus have a selected option no results are shown.

I want that results are shown even if only one or two select menus have options selected. This means a query with an empty `$_POST` value should be ignored, but the others should be executed. How can I handle that?

Comment: You'll probably need to show us the surrounding code so we can understand what the final query would look like. P.s. this is wide open to SQL injection attacks, you need to fix that urgently

Comment: That's because you're including an `AND` regardless of whether there will be a next condition. You have to make the `AND`s conditional as well.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. But how do I get the "AND" conditional?

Comment: You have two where clauses. Since the 2nd isn't conditional, you should remove the **WHERE 1=1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that the $_POST variables are all sent, because they are all part of the same form, so the resulting query has all the conditions with `=''` for every field that is empty.

So you if you use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` your code should work

```
if(!empty($_POST["is_category"]))
{
    $query .= "item.Material = '".$_POST["is_category"]."' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST["is_category2"]))
{
    $query .= "itemSparse.OverallQualityID = '".$_POST["is_category2"]."' AND ";
}

if(!empty($_POST["is_category3"]))
{
    $query .= "itemSparse.StatModifier_bonusStat1 = '".$_POST["is_category3"]."' AND ";
}
```

However, do note that your query has a major sql injection vulnerability, so such code should not be used in a production environment. For a production server you need to use prepared statement.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put `WHERE 1=1` clause, that will result TRUE. After that you can append any `AND` clause.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 "

if(isset($_POST["is_category"]))
{
     $query .= " AND item.Material = '".$_POST["is_category"]."'";
}

if(isset($_POST["is_category2"]))
{
    $query .= " AND itemSparse.OverallQualityID = '".$_POST["is_category2"]."'";
}

if(isset($_POST["is_category3"]))
{
     $query .= " AND itemSparse.StatModifier_bonusStat1 = '".$_POST["is_category3"]."'";
 }
```

Also change this to use prepared statement, otherwise the query is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is what I´ve searched. But sadly I´ve a problem with implementing the `WHERE 1=1` clause. I´ve posted the complete code. Could you maybe  have a look why it doesn´t show any results now? Probably I set it in the wrong place.

Comment: Now you have 2 WHERE clauses. Remove the WHERE 1=1 or replace the second WHERE with AND. As you have a where clause for every occasion, it's better to remove the where 1=1 part.